# Set CheckBox on - off

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I made a custom checkbox with button by creatin a class of UIButton 
here is the class

```
import UIKit

class CheckBox: UIButton {
    // Images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_check_box")! as UIImage
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_check_box_outline_blank")! as UIImage

    // Bool property
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == self {
            isChecked = !isChecked
        }
    }
}
```

I have two checkboxes in the viewcontroller but I dont know how to set checkbox in the ViewController.class to do  when checkBox "Si" is checked, the checkbox "No" set unchecked like in the image

[image: Checkbox Si]

[image: Checkbox No]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CheckBox` class should adopt a delegation pattern so that it can advise its delegate (which in this case would be your view controller) that its value has changed.  Then in your view controller you can update the other checkbox as required:

```
protocol CheckBoxDelegate {
    func checkBoxDidChange(checkbox: CheckBox) -> Void
}

class CheckBox: UIButton {
    // Images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_check_box")! as UIImage
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_check_box_outline_blank")! as UIImage

    weak var delegate: CheckBoxDelegate? 
    // Bool property
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        isChecked = !isChecked
        self.delegate?.checkBoxDidChange(self)
    }
}
```

Then, in your View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CheckBoxDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var siCheckBox: CheckBox!   // Initialise some other way if you aren't using storyboard/nib
    @IBOutlet var noCheckBox: CheckBox!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.siCheckBox.delegate = self
        self.noCheckBox.delegate = self
    }

    //Mark: CheckBoxDelegate

    func checkBoxDidChange(checkbox: CheckBox) {
        if checkbox == self.siCheckBox {
            self.noCheckBox.isChecked = !checkbox.isChecked
        } else {
            self.siCheckBox.isChecked = !checkbox.isChecked
        }
    }
```

From a user experience point of view, I would question why you need both checkboxes.  A checkbox is an on/off control, so you would normally have text like "Select really great option?" with a single checkbox for yes/no; checked is yes, unchecked is no.

Comment: "From a user experience point of view, I would question why you need both checkboxes" U are right , but is because some time the customer wants the aplication be like that , by the way thx for the example i will test it

Answer (score 0):

I would move `func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton)` to the parent ViewController.

```
let siCheckBox = CheckBox()
let noCheckBox = CheckBox()

func checkBoxToggled(sender: AnyObject) {
    noCheckbox.isChecked = !noCheckbox.isChecked
    siCheckbox.isChecked = !siCheckbox.isChecked
}
```

This is only safe if you're sure at least 1 is always checked. Otherwise I would add an `if` statement to make sure at l is checked.